# Select fields from three tables using db_select()

Tags: database

```
SELECT u.`uid`,u.`name`,f.`field_user_first_name_value`,l.`field_user_last_name_value`,u.`mail` from users as u, field_data_field_user_first_name as f, field_data_field_user_last_name as l where f.entity_id = u.uid and l.entity_id = u.uid limit 10
```

Is there a way to write this using db_select function?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this.

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->join('field_data_field_user_first_name', 'f', 'f.entity_id = u.uid');
      ->join('field_data_field_user_last_name', 'l','l.entity_id = u.uid');
$result = $query
  ->fields('u', array('uid', 'name', 'mail'))
  ->fields('f', array('field_user_first_name_value'))
  ->fields('l', array('field_user_first_name_value'))
  ->execute()->fetchField();
```

Comment: it seem's correct.

Comment: the joins are giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->join('field_data_field_user_first_name', 'f', 'f.entity_id = u.uid');
$query->join('field_data_field_user_last_name', 'l','l.entity_id = u.uid');
$result = $query->fields('u', array('uid', 'name', 'mail'))->fields('f', array('field_user_first_name_value'))->fields('l', array('field_user_first_name_value'))->execute()->fetchField();
```